# JComponent: How can it resist smallification?

Tags: java, jcomponent

I have a custom JComponent that paints some stuff when `paint` is called. In a `Border` layout, though, it's `minimumSize` is not being respected. I've included this

```
@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    System.out.println("asking for min size");
    return MINIMUM_SIZE;
}
```

and it never gets called. I've also tried setting min size on the container that holds it, and on the JFrame that holds that. How can I put some limits in here?

Comment: @Thilo, I added the other 'l', jokes aren't funny with spelling errors.

Comment: How are you sizing the frame in the first place?  Is the component in the center of the border layout?  We don't really have enough to go on here.  I've never had a problem with pack() but it will use preferred size, not minimum size.  And there is really nothing to stop the user from dragging a frame smaller if that's what you mean.

Comment: @PSpeed, that's what I mean. But I've switched layouts and strategies now (it's been a few hours :)... so I'm good. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `BorderLayout` respects minimum sizes; it just sizes things to fit the container.  You should try another layout (perhaps `BoxLayout`).

Comment: Yeah, I'm in fact doing that. This is so Java, really: include a whole bunch of optional things that have normal names that don't mean normal things. Anyway, thanks and +1

Comment: GridBagLayout to the rescue :)